# C++ derived class and base copy constructor as pointer

Tags: c++

I have a base class `aaa` and two derived classes `bbb` and `ccc`.

Is it possible to declare the base class first and then reference it to its derived classes, to make them share the same reference of it ?

To show what I mean I wrote this small code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class aaa
{
    protected:

        int a;

    public:

        aaa(int _a)
        {
            a = _a;
        }

        aaa(aaa &_aaa) = default;
        aaa(aaa &&_aaa) = default;

        int get_a(void)
        {
            return a;
        }

        void set_a(int _a)
        {
            a = _a;
        }

        int *get_a_addr(void)
        {
            return &a;
        }
};

class bbb : public aaa
{   
    public:

        bbb(aaa &_aaa) : aaa(_aaa)
        {
            ;
        }

        bbb(aaa &&_aaa) : aaa(_aaa)
        {
            ;
        }
};

class ccc : public aaa
{
    public:

        ccc(aaa &_aaa) : aaa(_aaa)
        {
            ;
        }

        ccc(aaa &&_aaa) : aaa(_aaa)
        {
            ;
        }
};

int main(void)
{   
    aaa a(10);
    bbb b(std::ref(a));
    ccc c(std::ref(a));

    std::cout << "address of a" << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.get_a_addr() << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.get_a_addr() << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.get_a_addr() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But `b` and `c` clearly don't have access to the same memory area of `a::a`.

As far as I know the only way to accomplish this is using nested classes. Isn't possible the way I am trying to ?

Comment: I was like how does this code even compile just when you edited

Comment: You're using the wrong tool: What you want to do is called aggregation. Inheritance also kind-of aggregates, but it doesn't allow sharing the aggregated instances between different owners. BTW: Your wording is misleading, you talk about declaring classes but what you really mean is creating objects.

Comment: Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: By the way, your copy ctors should be taking a `const` reference. Also, your move ctors are calling the copy ctors: you need `... : aaa(std::move(_aaa))` to call the move ctors. This might not matter in this specific example, but in general it could.

Answer (score 1):

All three objects have a different instance of the a member. And since you return the address of the ˋaˋ member in ˋget_a_addressˋ and not its content, the return value differs for each object. I assume you want to return the same value (the content of the ˋaˋ object) for all these calls.

Answer (score 0):

No, each base class subobject is independent of all other subobjects. What you can do is have a fake base class, whose only job is to reference the real thing.

```
class realA
{
  void foo() { ... }
  void bar() { ... }
};

class a
{
   ...
   void foo() { impl->foo(); }
   void bar() { impl->bar(); }
   std::shared_ptr<realA> impl;
};
```

`a` behaves just like `realA` because it has all the same methods as `realA`, doing the same thing.

Your `b` and `c` still have separate `a` subobjects, but now they may share the same `realA` object, which is the class that does the real work.